# Javascript can't set variable value

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get this function to set sortedScores to a value... whenever i do console.log anywhere it seems to store the values right, but it can't actually set sortedScores properly...

```
function facebook(sortedfriends) {

        var myID;
        var access_token;
   FB.init({
        appId  : something,
            status : true,
            cookie : true,
            xfbml  : true,
   });

   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response, sortedfriends) {
           if(!response.session) {
               FB.login(function(response) {
                       myId = response.session.uid;
                       access_token = response.session.access_token;
                       //does stuff

                       if (!response.session) {
                           console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                       }
                   });
           }
           else if(response.session) {
               myId = response.session.uid;
               access_token = response.session.access_token;
           var D = new Array();
               this.access_token = access_token;
               FB.api('/me/feed?access_token=' + access_token + '&limit=100', function(response, sortedfriends) {
               for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
                           var msg = response.data[i];
                           D.push(msg);
               }
                       sortedfriends = somefunction(D, myID);
                       //i know somefunction works because if i do console.log(sortedfriends) it shows me the right values...

               });

           }
   });
}
```

when i try 
    var friends;
    facebook(friends);
friends is just undefined... halp?

Comment: Is it just me or is the misspelling **halp** more common than it should be? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @ChaosPandion: http://www.google.se/search?q=halp&hl=sv&client=firefox-a&hs=MaK&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=3yFUTo3bEYbHtAb0sOED&ved=0CDoQsAQ&biw=1074&bih=897

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear where you are trying to access sortedfriends, but I'm guessing that your issue is that the Facebook login is asynchronous, so the response comes some time later after the `facebook` function has completed.  Thus, if you're trying to use the sortedfriends data right after you call the `facebook` function, the data will not be there yet because the login call has not completed yet.

The only way to use the `sortedfriends` data is from the success handler to the login call (where your console.log already verifies that the data is there).  If you want to use it in other code, then call that other code from the success handler to the login call.  You cannot call that code right after calling the `facebook` function.

This logic will not work because of the asynchronous nature of the login call (it hasn't completed when the `facebook` call returns and execution continues after it:

```
var sortedfriends = [];
facebook(sortedfriends);
// use sortedfriends here
```

Instead, you have to do this type of structure:

```
var sortedfriends = [];
facebook(sortedfriends);
// nothing executes here
```

And, inside your facebook call where you have this, add a function call to whatever code you want to use the sortedfriends data:

```
       else if(response.session) {
           myId = response.session.uid;
           access_token = response.session.access_token;
       var D = new Array();
           this.access_token = access_token;
           FB.api('/me/feed?access_token=' + access_token + '&limit=100', function(response, sortedfriends) {
           for( i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
                       var msg = response.data[i];
                       D.push(msg);
           }
                   sortedfriends = somefunction(D, myID);
                   //i know somefunction works because if i do console.log(sortedfriends) it shows me the right values...
                   // call the rest of your code here that will use sortedfriends
                   doSomethingWithSortedFriends(sortedfriends);

           });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this'll work... but as I'm working with a partner this'll mean that we'll have to significantly rearrange the rest of the program... ah well. Is there another way by any chance? If I make sure facebook is completely executed can I have code that executes after it?

Comment: Some ajax calls can be made synchronous, but that's usually a lousy design decision because it locks up the browser during the time of the networking call.  Besides this is Facebook's API so you probably don't even have that option.  As such, you're just going to have to restructure the code to work off the completion function and do nothing after initiating the call.  That's just the life of making asynchronous networking calls in javascript (or any other language).  The way to make sure the facebook call is done is from the success callback - there is no better way.

Answer (score 0):

javascript functions do not change incoming references. You cannot pass `undefined` and expect it will become defined after the function executes.

Instead, you should make your `sortedFriends` a global variable and not pass it as function parameter. Please note, that the value of `sortedFriends` will be set after the ajax query inside `getLoginStatus` is executed, so you will not be able to use it immediately after you execute your `facebook` function.

Comment: That's weird... so I need some logic like if(!sortedfriends) sortedFriends = somefunction(D, myID)? Also, make sortedfriends a global variable so initialize it outside the function